# Pass an array from a php page to javascript on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

i'm trying to update an array called "vars" on a page from an array stored on a php page

i got one page sending an array

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(vars);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "woepanel.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        $('#sent').attr("bgcolor", "#00FF00");
        $('#notsent').attr("bgcolor", "#FFFFFF");
    }
```

php receiving it and writing to a file

```
<?php
$vars=json_decode($_POST['data']); 
?>
<?php echo $vars ?>
<?php
file_put_contents('vars.txt', print_r($vars, true));
?>
```

and that part all works

then i need php to pass it to another page so in php i have

```
<?php
$varjava = '["' . implode('", "', $vars) . '"]';
?>
```

then in javascript i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
   var vars = <?php echo $varjava ?>;
   alert (vars);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encode it once again in JSON directly:

```
function test() {
   var vars = <?php echo json_encode($vars) ?>;
   alert (vars);
};
```

JSON is valid JavaScript when assigned to a variable or passed to a function.

Comment: how does it know to look at woepanel.php to get $vars from it tho?

Comment: Is your third code sample a separate script? I thought it was in the same script as the second.

Comment: all the php is on a separate page, the first code sample is on page a, all the php is on "woepanel.php" and the 4th sample is on page b if that helps

Comment: If the 4th is a new page then it can't have access to the `$vars` unless you store it somewhere such as the session or on disk.

Comment: could i read it in from the text file php creates with my array in it?

Comment: my file looks like this

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => offline.png
    [2] => offline.png
    [3] => offline.png
    [4] => offline.png
    [5] => offline.png
    [6] => offline.png
    [7] => Group A
    [8] => Group B
    [9] => Group C
    [10] => Group D
    [11] => Group E
    [12] => Group F
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 
    [17] => 
    [18] => 
    [19] => 0
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 0
    [22] => 0
    [23] => 0
    [24] => 0
)

Comment: Yes but the problem is you're storing it in the `print_r()` format which is difficult to parse. If you store it as JSON then it's much easier. Example if stores as JSON: `$vars = json_decode(file_get_contents('vars.txt'));`

Comment: i think i tried that but it would not store an array so i had to use print_r, how would i write an array to my file using json instead of print_r?

Comment: To store as JSON, change your file_put_contents line to `file_put_contents('vars.txt', json_encode($vars));`

Comment: ok that works but now to pull it back to javascript its not liking $testvar = json_decode(file_get_contents('vars.txt'));  is there another step to pull it back and put it in a javascript array ?

Comment: If you're putting it into JavaScript, don't decode it because JSON is valid JavaScript, e.g. you could do `<script>var vars = <?php file_get_contents('vars.txt') ?>;</script>`